# assigning package to a new subfolder of an existing project

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have already all a series of folder of an existing project in java.

this is the tree folder:

```
-org
 -w3c
  -jidadmin
  -jigsaw
  -ecc...
```

I would create a new folder inside w3c in the way that all java files inside my new folder will belong to package `org.w3c.myfolder`. I tried with eclipse to put inside src folder my new java file package org.w3c.myfolder but eclipse creates inside src folder the path org.w3c.myfolder

Comment: @JacobRaihle Because I have to extract infos from a class inside this existing project so I will have to import to my project all the dependencies o that existing project.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow entirely, but I'll assume you have good reasons :) Are the existing packages contained in a "source folder" already? If so you should be able to add new packages in the same structure rather than in the "src" source folder. If not you can right-click the "org" folder or its parent if it has one and perform the "Use as Source Folder" action under the "Build Path" menu.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just confused by the fact that Eclipse displays packages in a flat way by default, rather than displaying them hierarchically, as folders. Click on the small triangle icon in the package explorer if you prefer a hierarchical view.

[image]

[image]